# how can i minimize my code if i have many variables in getopt

Tags: shell, getopts

actually i wanted to minimize my code , becauze if i have many variable from getopt like 20- 30 variable then the code becomes very very long

```
   usage(){ echo "usage" }
   ARGS=$(getopt -o : --long "message:,name:,help" -- "$@");
   eval set  -- "$ARGS";
   while true; do
        case "$1" in
                --help)
                        shift;
                        usage
                        exit 0; 
                        ;;
                --message)
                        shift;
                        if [ -n "$1" ]; then
                            message="$1"
                            shift;
                        fi
                        ;;
                --name)
                        shift;
                        if [ -n "$1" ]; then
                            name="$1"
                            shift;
                        fi
                        ;;
                --)
                        shift;
                        break;
                        ;;
        esac
     done
     if [ -z "$message" ]; then
         echo 'message cannot be empty'
         exit 1
     fi
     if [ -z "$name" ]; then
         echo 'default name:default'
         name=default
     fi
     echo name:"$name"
```

Updated: if have an option like help then how can i handle it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step would be an array:

```
key_value_options=(message name)
```

Then you munge them to create the `getopt` string:

```
getopt_options="$(printf %s:, "${key_value_options[@]}")"
```

For the `case` statement you join the options with pipe instead:

```
case_options="$(IFS='|' && echo "${key_value_options[*]}")"
```

Answer (score 1):

To flesh out l0b0's answer

```
declare -A values
key_value_options=(message name foo bar baz)
getopt_options="$(printf %s:, "${key_value_options[@]}")"
eval set  -- "$(getopt -o : --long "$getopt_options" -- "$@")"
while true; do
    var=${1#--}  # strip the leading hyphens
    shift
    [[ -z $var ]] && break
    values[$var]=$1
    shift
done

if [[ -z ${values[message]} ]]; then
     echo 'message cannot be empty'
     exit 1
fi

# shorthand for setting a default value
: ${values[name]:=default}    

for var in "${!values[@]}"; do
    printf "%s:%s\n" $var "${values[$var]}"
done
```

In action

```
$ bash test.sh
message cannot be empty
$ bash test.sh --message foo
name:default
message:foo
$ bash test.sh --message foo --foo qux
name:default
foo:qux
message:foo
$ bash test.sh --message foo --foo qux --name name --unknown option
name:name
foo:qux
message:foo
```

Comment: I didn't use a case statement: `getopt` will remove invalid options.

Comment: You don't need to `declare` an array, and you should use `-a` - `-A` declares an *associative* array.

Comment: I know, I need an associative array in my answer: the array keys are the option names (I can't tell if your comment is for me or for others)